# Using IGeoProcessor2 to update Oracle Spatial

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

In the below example the input and out are shape files read from folders.Is it possible to read and write Oracle Spatial Geometry tables? I have ArcGIS,ArcSDE and Oracle Spatial 11g.
How to set parameters to create a new Geometry table if it does not exist?
How to append the data if a geometry table already exists ?

```c#
IGeoProcessor2 pGeoProcessor = new GeoProcessorClass();
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
parameters.Add(pFlayer);
parameters.Add(OutLayerPath + "\\" + pFlayer.Name + "MBM.shp");
parameters.Add("CIRCLE");
parameters.Add("NONE");
parameters.Add("");
parameters.Add("MBG_FIELDS");
pGeoProcessor.Execute("MinimumBoundingGeometry_management", parameters, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out,the below should work :

```c#
IGeoProcessor2 pGeoProcessor = new GeoProcessorClass();
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
parameters.Add(@"Database Connections\" +MySDE.SDE + "\\" + DB_MBM_InputTable);
parameters.Add(@"Database Connections\" +MySDE.SDE + "\\" + DB_MBM_OutputTable);
parameters.Add("CIRCLE");
parameters.Add("NONE");
parameters.Add("");
parameters.Add("MBG_FIELDS");
pGeoProcessor.Execute("MinimumBoundingGeometry_management", parameters, null);
```